# Paypal Developer Apps

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Does anyone know if the REST API Paypal Apps you can create that use OAuth for Authentication allow other paypal accounts to authenticate your app access to their accounts? Or is it only meant for the account that creates the app to use it?

I guess another way to ask it is are these apps available to the public to authorize access to their accounts or are they private to the accounts that create the apps?

Thank you

Comment: are you thinking Login with PayPal?

Comment: nope, was talking about this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

but found out that paypal apps don't actually even use OAuth 2.0 even though the docs say they do..